# ionic 2 nav push - from right direction

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I modify the the navPush in a way that new pages enter from the right instead of from the bottom? (there should be some parameters but I didn't find them inside the ionic docs

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by setting the `animate` property. The only problem is that the `push` method only could be animated

- from bottom to top: `{ animate: true, direction: 'forward' }`
- from top to bottom: `{ animate: true, direction: 'back' }`

You can still use the `setRoot()` method like this to achieve the animation you're looking for:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
```

Please find more information in [this page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#navoptions).